# RxSwift - Who is the Observer?

Tags: swift, observable

I've just started studying Rxswift lately. And there's this one question that's been bothering me since. Take this code snippet for example:

```
class MyClass {
    var v = Variable("")
    var bag = DisposeBag()
    func subscribe() {
        let ob = v.asObservable()
        ob.subscribe(onNext: { (value) in
            print("Value changed: " + value)
        }).disposed(by: bag)
    }
}
```

What bothers me is, where/who is the real **observer** in the scenario of **subscribe()** method? In term of objects, here we have *ob* who acts as an observable, but I can't really see the observer object anywhere.

Can anyone pls brighten my mind?

Answer (score 1):

The observer in the example above is really the *closure* which you provide to the `subscribe(onNext:)` function.

Of course, how long that closure sticks around is determined by the lifetime of your `DisposeBag`: when your instance of `MyClass` dies, `bag` dies, and therefore the closure dies. For this reason, you may find people calling your instance of `MyClass` the "observer".